# How to increase root (/) partition size using command line?

Tags: partitioning, ext3

I am running Ubuntu 16.0.4LTS 32-bit on my hdd with:

```
50GB for root (/)
60GB for home (/home)
```

My system shows me that my root partition is `out of space`, and because of it many applications are not working properly.

My home partition is about 40% full.
Is there a way( command line ) that I could increase the root partition size and get that space from home partition. Both root and home partitions are ext3 filesystems.

Comment: Please post the output of `sudo parted -l`

Comment: Model: ATA ST9160314AS (scsi)  
Disk /dev/sda: 160GB  
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B  
Partition Table: msdos  
Disk Flags:   

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system     Flags  
 1      1049kB  53.7GB  53.7GB  primary  ext3  
 2      53.7GB  118GB   64.4GB  primary  ext3  
 3      118GB   160GB   41.9GB  primary  linux-swap(v1)

Comment: Why a 42GB swap partition? How much RAM do you have? I'd take away from there to add to / or /home. Cheers, Al

Comment: I think I am able to fix this issue. I used a live USB stick to boot and then I am using GParted to re-arrange the partitions. Deleted the swap, moved the home parition and then increased the root partition size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I fixed it was to boot a live USB stick with Ubuntu and connected my hard drive whose root partition was out of space. Started GParted and resized/moved the paritions. Depending upon what you are doing, it might take sometime.